# Loading user input into an array then display

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to get user input from HTML form and then get it into an array in `javascript`. Afterwards output it back into the div tag in HTML as a list.

The code works but it outputs the text twice instead of just once.

Example: user inputs `orange` in HTML form, then inputs `apple`, then `banana`

My code makes it output: `orange, orange, apple, orange, apple, banana`

It should just output: `orange, apple, banana`

```js
// global variable
var enteredStringsArray = [];

function listArray() {
 "use strict";
 var form;
 var enteredText;
 var enteredString;
 var index;

 form = document.getElementById("lab06");
 enteredText = form.text.value;

 enteredStringsArray.push(enteredText);

 enteredString = document.getElementById("theOrderedList");

 for (index = 0; index < enteredStringsArray.length; index++) {
  enteredString.innerHTML += "<li>" + enteredStringsArray[index] + "  </li>";
 }

 return false;
}
```

```html
<form id="list" action="#" onsubmit="return listArray();">
 <label>Text:</label>
 <input type="text" id="textId" name="text" />
 <br/>
 <input type="submit" name="runForm" value="submit" />
</form>
<div id="outputDiv" class="Output">
 <ol id="theOrderedList"></ol>
</div>
```

Comment: have updated an answer, check out

Answer (score 0):

You can try without `forloop`, just create new *`li`* element and append in your *`ol`*

```js
// global variable
var enteredStringsArray = [];
function lab06firstArrays() {
    "use strict";
    var enteredText;
    enteredText = document.getElementById("textId").value;
    enteredStringsArray.push(enteredText);
    console.log(enteredStringsArray);
    var ul = document.getElementById("theOrderedList");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(enteredText));
    ul.appendChild(li);
    document.getElementById("textId").value= "";
    return false;
}
```

```html
<form id="lab06" action="#" onsubmit="return lab06firstArrays();">
<label>Text:</label>
<input type="text" id="textId" name="text" />
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="runForm" value="submit" />
</form>
<br/>
<div id="outputDiv" class="Output">
  <ol id="theOrderedList"></ol>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

With `forloop`:

```js
// global variable
var enteredStringsArray = [];
function lab06firstArrays() {
    "use strict";
    var enteredText;
    enteredText = document.getElementById("textId").value;
    enteredStringsArray.push(enteredText);
    //console.log(enteredStringsArray);
     var ul = document.getElementById("theOrderedList");
    for (var i= enteredStringsArray.length - 1; i < enteredStringsArray.length; i++)
    {
      var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(enteredText));
    ul.appendChild(li);
    document.getElementById("textId").value= "";
    }
    return false;
}
```

```html
<form id="lab06" action="#" onsubmit="return lab06firstArrays();">
<label>Text:</label>
<input type="text" id="textId" name="text" />
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="runForm" value="submit" />
</form>
<br/>
<div id="outputDiv" class="Output">
  <ol id="theOrderedList"></ol>
</div>
```

Comment: This way works but I need to incorporate a loop to get it to output.

Comment: What do you want from `forloop`? That means required *abc* inside loop

Comment: I need the for loop to go through the array and output each text one by one as a list. If that clarifies for you. So basically what you did but in a for loop instead.

Comment: @M.P.T. Why do you _need_ a loop?

Comment: @M.P.T. you are getting values in array itself for further use:)

Comment: You can do, by clear existing `*li*` from `*ol*` and add from fresh, but i would not recomanded this!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale it works which is great! But I haven't learned how to use: appendChild, document.createElement, nor createTextNode. Trying to do what you did without using those elements.

Comment: You can read on Google but do you required the answer without this?

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
for (index = 0; index < enteredStringsArray.length; index++) {
        enteredString.innerHTML += "<li>" + enteredStringsArray[index] + " 
        </li>";
    }
```

from

```
enteredString.innerHTML += "<li>" + enteredText + "</li>";
```

it will work. Add each input items one by one. no need to loop it.

Comment: This works but I am required to use a loop to get it to output. Therefore I have the for loop. Trying to get that figured.

Comment: then add enteredString.innerHTML = ''; after enteredString = document.getElementById("theOrderedList"); and keep the for loop.